# Как сделать замену вводимой пользователем запятой в поле input на точку?

Tags: javascript, замена

Как сделать чтобы в калькуляторе запятая, введенная посетителем сайта, менялась на точку?

```
<script lang="JavaScript">
    function I(form) {
        P=eval(form.P.value);
        f1=eval(form.f1.value);
        C1=(P * f1 * Math.PI)/1000;
        form.total.value = C1;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: На чем сделан канкулятор на сайте?

Comment: <form>
  <script lang="JavaScript">
    function I(form) {
      P=eval(form.P.value);
      f1=eval(form.f1.value);
      C1=(P * f1 * Math.PI)/1000
      form.total.value = C1;
    }
  </script>

Comment: Возможно вам сюда http://javascript.ru/string/replace

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю